# Make RangeSelector into dropdown Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Instead of displaying it like the common Rangeselector display, is there a way to make it like a dropdown? Appreciate your help with this. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use exporting module to generate a custom button with a dropdown feature. Inside `exporting.buttons.toggle` object you can create `menuItems` array which will contain list of the buttons. Each button has onclick event which will let you to call `rangeSelector.clickButton(index, redraw)` function, responsible for selecting a specific range. Lastly, you can hide original range selector, for example using CSS:

```
.highcharts-range-selector-buttons {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/exporting.buttons
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8rrotg5a/